# Is it possible to use nHibernate with Paradox database?

Tags: database, nhibernate, paradox

Is it possible to configure nHibernate to connect to Paradox database (`*.db` files)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, sort of.

There is no support included in the trunk, you need to write your own dialect.  Or you can port the [Paradox dialect created for Hibernate](http://www.hxtt.com/hibernate.html).